# laravel 5.2 500 error on apache 2.4 and Centos 7

Tags: apache, laravel, centos

I have `apache 2.4` on my both local and server machine, local one use `ubuntu 12.04` server use `Centos 7`. I try combine old `fuzybox` framework in '/var/www/html/projectx' directory and laravel 5.2 framework in '/var/www/html/projectx/api' directory.

project directories:

> Local laravel  `/var/www/html/api/`
>
> Remote laravel `/var/www/html/projectx/api/`

permissions in server public folder setted 777 for test:

> ```
> [user@xxx]# ls -l /var/www/html/projectx/api/
> total 184
> ...
> drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4096 2016-04-13 13:22 public
> ...
> ```

My 'projectx.com' url open fuzybox app, when i go to url `projectx.com/api` I get api directory files and folders list, it show that http server work and i can reach api directory, but when I go to `projectx.com/api/public` I get error 500. On my local machine every works fine.

virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName projectx.com
        ServerAlias projectx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectx
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/projectx/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/projectx/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

also I tried bottom virtual configurations but get some 500 error when go to `projectx.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName projectx.com
        ServerAlias projectx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectx/api/public
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/projectx/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/projectx/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Problem was with php version, after update to php 5.6 lavarel start work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your web server to a `public` directory to make Laravel work. For example, if you installed Laravel into `/var/www/html/projectx/api/` directory, you can use these Apache settings.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/projectx/api/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/projectx/api/public">
```

Do not forget to restart Apache after these changes.

Then just use simple routes for your API:

```
Route::get('api/getSomething', 'ApiController@getSomething');
```

And use URLs similar to this:

```
projectx.com/api/getSomething
```

Comment: I cant change DocumentRoot becouse my main app is fuzybox for render html, I want use laravel to process front-end ajax requests. see edited post.

Comment: Using Laravel in a subfolder is a bad idea, because you'll have a lot of headaches if you'll try to make everything work. Better solution is to use sub-domain like `api.projectx.com` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: Also I tried change DocumentRoot by you way but get same 500 error.

Comment: Check permissions of `storage` directory. Or run `chmod -R 775 storage` in the Laravel firectory. Also, it may be conflict between Laravel and Fusebox (you said it's installed in the root directory).

Comment: ls -l : drwxrwxrwx  5 root root   4096 2016-04-12 14:38 storage